# How to install mlxtend in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, mlxtend

I tried to perform some task using mlxtend then I got error messages

I have checked the thread with a similar problem and none seems to address my own situation.

I tried to install from anaconda prompt with the following codes:

- `conda install mlxtend`
- `conda install mlxtend --channel conda-forge`

But none of these codes seems to be working for me.

I expected a success download report but rather I got the following:

```
       administrator: False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve

future releases of conda.

Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]: yes

Upload successful.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.

Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)

by running.
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!
 could you provide more details on the error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try pip install mlxtend instead of Vonda install

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.